# Custom Dictionary for Tesseract

Tags: android, dictionary, ocr, tesseract

I am currently working on a project for android using Tesseract OCR. I was hoping to fine-tune the results given to the user by adding a dictionary. According to [tesseract OCR wiki](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ), the best way to go about this would be to

> Replace tessdata/eng.user-words with your own word list, in the same
> format - UTF8 text, one word per line.

However there is no eng.user-words file in the tessdata folder, I assume that if I just make a text file with my dictionary in it, it will never be used...

Has anybody had a similar experience and knows what to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using `tesseract 3` (which I assume you are).
You'll have to rebuild your `eng.trainddata` file.

I intended to replace the word-dawg file completely to try to get better results (ie - the words I'm detecting are always the same).

You'll need `combine_tessdata` and `wordlist2dawg` executables in the training directory when you compile tesseract.

1. unpack everything (i did this just to back up my eng.word-dawg, you'll also need the unicharset later)

   `./combine_tessdata -u eng.traineddata`
2. create a textfile of your wordlist (wordlistfile)
3. create a eng.word-dawg

   `./wordlist2dawg wordlistfile eng.word-dawg traineddat_backup/.unicharset`
4. replace the word-dawg file

   `./combine_tessdata -o eng.traineddata eng.word-dawg`

that should be it.

Comment: I am trying to execute this step 3 but having this error
`Loading unicharset from 'traineddat_backup/.unicharset'
Failed to load unicharset from 'traineddat_backup/.unicharset'`
Kindly help me I am trying to do it on Ubuntu 12.04 and tesseract 3.02.

Comment: @MuhammadMuaz: `traineddat_backup/.unicharset` is the path to folder of the output of 1st cmd. If the first cmd was `./combine_tessdata -u ita.traineddata /path/to/folder/tmp/ita.` the 3rd is `./wordlist2dawg wordlist ita.word-dawg /path/to/folder/tmp/ita.unicharset`. Hope it helps, I throw away 30 minutes on that.